# Django ORM object count

Tags: python, django, django-orm

Consider these pseudo models:

```
class BaseProduct:
   quantity_available = Integer

class Box(BaseProduct):
   items_in_box = Integer

>> BaseProduct.objects.count()
>> Integer
```

But how do I retrieve the total number of products, so:

```
for each object[quantity_available * items_in_box] * total_objects
```

## Solution:

I used Simeon Visser's 'sum' as a partial solution, adding a property to the Base class:

```
@property
def _box_count(self):
    try:
        return self.items_in_box * self.quantity_available
    except AttributeError:
        return self.quantity_available

sum([item._box_count for item in BaseProduct.objects.all()])
```

Comment: I don't understand. Are you looking for the total number of boxes, or the total number of items? And how are `items_in_box` and `quantity_available` related?

Comment: how do you manage the inheritance from `BaseProduct` to `Box` in the database?  Do you use one of the methods outlined in the docs? https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/#model-inheritance

Comment: A BaseProduct has a quantity_available field (integer). A Box is an inheritance from BaseProduct, also a Box can hold X products. Say you sell umbrella's, per piece and per box. I want the total stock of umbrella's

Comment: No I define a custom as_leaf_class, something like http://djangosnippets.org/snippets/1034/

Comment: So what do you have? Umbrella(BaseProduct) and BoxOfUmbrellas(BaseProduct) or something else?

Comment: so, I'm assuming then that your database will have two tables in it, a BaseProduct table and a Box table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following:

```
sum([box.quantity_available * box.items_in_box for box in Box.objects.all()]
```

It retrieves all the boxes and for each box, it computes the quanitity available of that box times the number of items in boxes of that type. Lastly, it sums all these values so you get the total number of products.

Comment: This seems the pragmatic approach, I opt in a property to the model though, thanks